# How to query a JSON object in Groovy, using only Groovy or native Java libraries

Tags: java, json, groovy, jsonpath, jsonslurper

I've tried a few different way of doing this. I have a JSON string that I'm parsing with JSONSlurper that looks like this, and I want to get the value with a key==StoreID2.

```
    {
    "EmailData": {
        "MessageRecords": [
            {
                "To": "this@that.com",
                "FieldData": [
                    {
                        "key": "StoreName",
                        "value": "Livonia"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "StoreID2",
                        "value": "7017"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With JSONPath I can get the value like this: `$.EmailData.MessageRecords[0].FieldData[?(@.key=="StoreID2")].value`  But it doesn't look like Groovy has JSONPath available, without loading a non-native library (com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse), which I'm trying to avoid.

This is actually the solution:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper(); 
def jsonObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(inputSB.toString());
logger.info("Store: " + jsonObject.EmailData.MessageRecords[0].FieldData.find{it.key=='StoreID2'}.value);
```

Thanks

Comment: `FieldData` is an array, not a map, so its contents are not randomly accessible by key.

Comment: `FieldData` is an array. and to find element in array by some property - you have to iterate it.

Comment: if you want to access multiple elements from it - you could convert it to map: `FieldData = FieldData.collectEntries{ [it.key,it.value] }`

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. Keep in mind there's a syntax error in your json (missing comma after the 'to' field)

Comment: Ha. You're right @JoeriHendrickx